# "Failed to get document because the client is offline" only on web app - Firebase Firestore on Flutter

Tags: flutter, firebase, google-cloud-firestore, web-applications

I'm using FireFlutter to store data in the Firebase Firestore.

The web app returns this error:

```
Error: [cloud_firestore/unavailable] Failed to get document because the client is offline.
```

Steps to reproduce:

1- Create a new Firebase project (no Analytics) and activate Firestore in test mode; add a collection called test with a document called test and some dummy data; from the project settings, add a new web app and copy the CDN instructions in the web/index.html file just before the closing body tag;

2- Create a new Flutter project (I use VSCode and ask it to create an empty application);

3- Add firebase_Core and cloud_firestore dependencies

4- In the terminal, use fireflutter configure, using the Firebase project just created; for this test I only build the web application;

5- Add

```
WidgetsFlutterBinding.ensureInitialized();
await Firebase.initializeApp(
    options: DefaultFirebaseOptions.currentPlatform,
);
```

in the main function and

```
MainApp({super.key}) {
    FirebaseFirestore.instance
            .collection('test')
            .doc('test')
            .get()
            .then((value) {
                print(value);
            }).catchError((error) {
                print(error);
            });
    }
}
```

in the MainApp class constructor;

6- Run the Flutter project

The debug console shows the error described above.

The connection is not a problem, no ad blocker is activated.
Mobile versions work, this makes me think the problem could be in some configuration file, but I don't understand what to check.

Can anyone point me to the right direction?

Comment: Does this [thread](https://stackoverflow.com/a/70362119/20239914) helps for your query

Comment: In the thread it is considered the case where there is no connection, but this is not my case: the site is correctly downloaded from the hosting service and also mobile versions are able to perform the request from the same device. Thank you, however

Comment: can you provide reproducible steps so that it can be recreated and solved in that way ?

Comment: The solution is still unclear: I changed the code, I changed the settings in Firebase, I double checked everything, but no luck. The only variable I had not checked was the local machine. Formatting the OS solved the problem, but I don't know what the problem was.

Comment: Are you using FireFlutter or [FlutterFire](https://firebase.flutter.dev/) asking because of your first line `I'm using FireFlutter to store data in the Firebase Firestore`. If you are using FlutterFire then you can use flutterfire cli tool to configure the sdk automatically into your app. But here you are using automatic and manual both at same time means either configure with [flutterfire cli](https://firebase.flutter.dev/docs/cli) of configure with [manual installation](https://firebase.flutter.dev/docs/manual-installation)

Comment: I use FlutterFire, I must edit the text

Comment: @marcolav have you found a solution to this?

Comment: No, sorry. As I wrote above formatting the OS removed the problem, I don't know what caused it

Answer (score 1):

I have recreated the setup based on your Steps provided and I also got the same error as yours when I tried this even on a slow network as well.

Your 1st step is counteracting the 4th step, you are configuring the flutterfire sdk with both automatic installation and manual installation at the same time.

I recommend you to configure either with [cli](https://firebase.flutter.dev/docs/cli) or with [manual installation](https://firebase.flutter.dev/docs/manual-installation/web).

When Configuring with only one of the methods the error has gone for me.

Comment: You are right, but even deleting the lines from index.html I couldn't connect to the server. Thank you for reviewing the problem!